# icCube excel reporting - changing data with the same schema

Tags: iccube

I am able to connect to an existing cube from Excel. I am then trying to connect this same Excel file to a different Cube that has the same schema but a completely different set of dimensions and measures.

However, when I try to refresh the file against the new cube, Excel stays in the "Executing OLAP query" state indefinitely and on the icCube server I see COMMON_GENERAL_ERROR with a null message. It seems that the problem happens because icCube is trying to pull data based on old dimension values  that are in my PivotTable filters and since these values don't exist in the new cube, I'm getting an error. The dimensions in question have an All member and I was hoping that in such cases the query would use the All member. Is this possible and/or am I missing some settings in my schema definition?

Comment: Please send the log files to the icCube support for further investigation.